# A polynomial question.

Tags: polynomials, binomial-coefficients

I came across this question in my weekly test paper and didn't know how to tackle it. The question goes as follows:
$a_0,a_1,a_2....a_{34}$ are the coefficients of $x^0,x^1,x^2......x^{34}$ of the polynomial obtained on opening the parenthesis of $(1+x+x^2)^{17}$, then which is true?

$1)~a_1+a_2+.......+ a_{34}$ is even;

$2)~a_1=17$;

$3)~a_{33}=17$;

$4)~a_2=153$.

(One or more is correct)

Comment: You can deduce what $a_{1,2}$ are with a small bit of expanding.  Not sure if there are any tricks for $a_{33}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some info regarding (2) - (4)

> - Ad (2): $a_1$ is the coefficient of $x^1$ in $(1+x+x^2)^{17}$. Since there are $17$ factors of the form $1+x+x^2$ we have to choose precisely from one factor $x$ whereas from all other factors we have to choose $1$. This can be done in
>     \begin{align*}
>   a_1=\binom{17}{1}=17
>   \end{align*}
>     different ways.
> - Ad (3): The polynomial $1+x+x^2=x\left(\frac{1}{x}+1+x\right)$ has a nice symmetrical structure. This implies the coefficient of $x^k$ in $(1+x+x^2)^{17}$ is also the coefficient of $x^{34-k}$ with $0\leq k \leq 34$. We conclude
>     \begin{align*}
>   a_{33}=a_{34-1}=a_1=17
>   \end{align*}
> - Ad (4): $a_2$ is the coefficient of $x^2$ in $(1+x+x^2)^{17}$. In order to get $x^2$ from $17$ factors of the form $1+x+x^2$ we have to choose one factor $x^2$ which can be done in $\binom{17}{1}$ different ways and $1$ from the remaining $16$ factors, or we have to choose two factors $x$ which can be done in $\binom{17}{2}$ different ways and $1$ from the remaining $15$ factors. We conclude
>     \begin{align*}
>   a_2=\binom{17}{1}+\binom{17}{2}=17+\frac{1}{2}\cdot 17\cdot 16=153
>   \end{align*}

Comment: D: Sorry that you haven't gotten much attention for your good answer that looks like you had put good effort into.  And neat trick for the $a_{33}$, you deserve my +1

Comment: Awesome! U have explained it in a very clear manner. Thank u!

Comment: @SimpleArt: No worries! Many thanks for your nice comment!

Comment: @LokeshSangewar: You're welcome! Good to see the answer is useful. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial response: the sum listed in (1) is almost the same as plugging in $x=1$ to the polynomial. The only difference is that you will not have the constant term $a_0=1$. Let $f(x)$ be your polynomial. Then $f(1)=3^{17}$ which is an odd number. Your sum is 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=1}^{34}a_j&=f(1)-a_0\\
&=3^{17}-1
\end{align*}
The sum is even!

Comment: so that's for the first....For the others?

Comment: It looks like they are all correct.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: if you plug $x=1$ in, you will get the sum of the coefficients.

The coefficients may be represented using [Viete's formulas.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi%C3%A8te's_formula)

Comment: What is viete's formula?

Comment: @LokeshSangewar see my edits.

Comment: Ok I understood it. Thanks